# SLD file already exists

Tags: geoserver

Using Geoserver 2.1.3 I do delete sld using rest api with manually delete the sld file. But when I issue a POST new sld with the same name I got an error "SLD file test.sld already exists." Event there is no test.sld in the styles folder.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you share the POST request you used?

Comment: Same problem here with Geoserver 2.9. Even after deleting via web interface the error pops up.